# Make input tag into a drop down list

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to make an input tag have a selection of events when I click on it.

It would look something like this? :

```
<input type="text"/>
<select name="Expiration Month">
<option value="January">January</option>
....
</select>
```

What I want the image to look like is this.[image: Drop down menu]

Comment: What's the idea of this? Anyway, this is not possible, `input` is an empty element, and it can't have HTML.

Comment: You'll probably have to simulate that with some javascript and divs. Or use a toolkit that supports this, I think the jQuery UI had something like that

Comment: Are you looking for an actual input with a dropdown? or are you looking to style your `select` to look like your inputs?

Comment: I want my input to have a dropdown menu of options for months: e.g. jan, feb, march, etc. 

But I'm looking at javascript/jquery now because I can't find anything using CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many JS libraries which will help you with the JavaScript and CSS that you need. As an example if you are using JQuery you can use JQuery UI to do what you want.

For more information go to http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Answer (score 9):

Hope this helps!

```
<form method="post">
  <input list="browsers">
  <datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">
    <option value="Firefox">
    <option value="Chrome">
    <option value="Opera">
    <option value="Safari">
  </datalist> 
</form>
```